# How to catch specific Exception

Tags: php, exception

I sometimes get in the log `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Connection reset by peer` on `socket_read()`

How can I catch and ignore only this one exception, re-throwing any other?

Comment: Your question is not complete. add some code samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example handles all exceptions.  If the exception contains the phrase, it allows you to handle that, otherwise, it rethrows an error message.

```
try {
  // Your Code
} catch (Exception $e) {

  if ( ! strpos($e->getMessage(), "Connection reset by peer") === false )
      throw $e; // THROW IT, ITS A DIFFERENT ERROR
  else
  {
      // Do Your Handling Code
  }
}
```

Comment: Should you really have `!` there?